# AxWMPLib.AxWindowsMediaPlayer transitions settings?

Tags: c#, transition, axwindowsmediaplayer

I'm building an app with media player, using `AxWMPLib.AxWindowsMediaPlayer` for this purpose. So, while writing `PlayStateChange` handler, I've discovered, there's state `9` which is `"Transitioning"` according to [official docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562460(v=vs.85).aspx). Nevertheless I've found nothing about transitions settings. So, is it possible to setup transitions? If so, then how to do this? If it's not, then what `"Transitioning"` state really means?

Comment: It is chatty, assume that the player is moving from one song to another.  It takes some time to find the next file and start decoding it.  Be careful what you do, the player doesn't like to be messed with while the event is running.  Not doing anything at all is quite reasonable, "Transitioning" doesn't last very long on a modern machine and the user expects a slight pause.

Comment: @HansPassant is it possible to make some transition effects with AxWindowsMediaPlayer methods?

Comment: I figured that "the player doesn't like to be messed with" would be important to include in the comment.  It is unambiguous.

Comment: @HansPassant So, if I want to show an image for several seconds on media change or to do a cross dissolving, I have to make it without any AxWindowsMediaPlayer usage?